# React-Native Flatlist error: Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

As soon as I add more than 1 comment, I get this error. I'm guessing there is some syntax issue with the latest version of react-native because it's not able to read the array of comments. Please help.

```
          <FlatList
            refreshing={this.state.refresh}
            data={this.state.comments_list}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "#eee" }}
            renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
              <View key={index} style={styles.flatListViewItems}>
                <View style={{ padding: 5, width: "100%", flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "space-between" }}>
                  <Text>time :{item.posted}</Text>
                  <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() =>
                      this.props.navigation.navigate("User", {
                        userId: item.authorId
                      })
                    }
                  >
                    <Text style={{ paddingRight: 5 }}>{item.author}</Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
                <View style={{ padding: 5 }}>
                  <Text>{item.comment}</Text>
                </View>
              </View>
            )}
          />
```

This is the Error Message. {6cb9-63e3-ec5b-b764-6d3c, comment-id-1} are the id's of the two comments. comment-id-1 was the first comment and as soon as I created a new comment, it automatically generated an id for it: 6cb9-63e3-ec5b-b764-6d3c, and now since there are two comments in the array, it is not able to display it on the screen :

```
Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {6cb9-63e3-ec5b-b764-6d3c, comment-id-1}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in RCTText (at Text.js:145)
    in TouchableText (at Text.js:268)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in AnimatedComponent (at TouchableOpacity.js:256)
    in TouchableOpacity (at comments.js:271)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in CellRenderer (at VirtualizedList.js:687)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in RCTScrollView (at ScrollView.js:977)
    in ScrollView (at VirtualizedList.js:1062)
    in VirtualizedList (at FlatList.js:662)
    in FlatList (at comments.js:255)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in comments (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (at StackViewLayout.js:795)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in AnimatedComponent (at StackViewCard.js:69)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in AnimatedComponent (at screens.native.js:59)
    in Screen (at StackViewCard.js:57)
    in Card (at createPointerEventsContainer.js:27)
    in Container (at StackViewLayout.js:860)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in ScreenContainer (at StackViewLayout.js:311)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in AnimatedComponent (at StackViewLayout.js:307)
    in Handler (at StackViewLayout.js:300)
    in StackViewLayout (at withOrientation.js:30)
    in withOrientation (at StackView.js:79)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in Transitioner (at StackView.js:22)
    in StackView (created by Navigator)
    in Navigator (at createKeyboardAwareNavigator.js:12)
    in KeyboardAwareNavigator (at createAppContainer.js:388)
    in NavigationContainer (at App.js:57)
    in App (at withExpoRoot.js:22)
    in RootErrorBoundary (at withExpoRoot.js:21)
    in ExpoRootComponent (at renderApplication.js:34)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:33)

This error is located at:
    in RCTText (at Text.js:145)
    in TouchableText (at Text.js:268)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in AnimatedComponent (at TouchableOpacity.js:256)
    in TouchableOpacity (at comments.js:271)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in CellRenderer (at VirtualizedList.js:687)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in RCTScrollView (at ScrollView.js:977)
    in ScrollView (at VirtualizedList.js:1062)
    in VirtualizedList (at FlatList.js:662)
    in FlatList (at comments.js:255)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in comments (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (at StackViewLayout.js:795)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in AnimatedComponent (at StackViewCard.js:69)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in AnimatedComponent (at screens.native.js:59)
    in Screen (at StackViewCard.js:57)
    in Card (at createPointerEventsContainer.js:27)
    in Container (at StackViewLayout.js:860)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in ScreenContainer (at StackViewLayout.js:311)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in AnimatedComponent (at StackViewLayout.js:307)
    in Handler (at StackViewLayout.js:300)
    in StackViewLayout (at withOrientation.js:30)
    in withOrientation (at StackView.js:79)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in Transitioner (at StackView.js:22)
    in StackView (created by Navigator)
    in Navigator (at createKeyboardAwareNavigator.js:12)
    in KeyboardAwareNavigator (at createAppContainer.js:388)
    in NavigationContainer (at App.js:57)
    in App (at withExpoRoot.js:22)
    in RootErrorBoundary (at withExpoRoot.js:21)
    in ExpoRootComponent (at renderApplication.js:34)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in RCTView (at View.js:44)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:33)
```

Comment: This error tells that you are rendering an object inside of `Text`. It should be raw text. Try `console.warn(item)` and see what object you are rendering. And do you have those properties.

Answer (score 1):

Text component can't render an object. Just like the error shows. 
Try changing this line:

```
<Text style={{ paddingRight: 5 }}>{item.author}</Text>
```